# Graph implementation C++

Tags: c++, graph

I was wondering about a quick to write implementation of a graph in c++. I need the data structure to be easy to manipulate and use graph algorithms(such as BFS,DFS, Kruskal, Dijkstra...).
I need this implementation for an algorithms Olympiad, so the easier to write the data structure the better.

Can you suggest such DS(main structs or classes and what will be in them). I know that an Adjacency list and Adjacency matrix are the main possibilities, but I mean a more detailed **code** sample.

For example I thought about this DS last time I had to implement a graph for DFS:

```
struct Edge {
  int start;
  int end;
  struct Edge* nextEdge;
}
```

and then used a array of size n containing in its i'th place the Edge List(struct Edge) representing the edges starting in the i'th node.

but when trying to DFS on this graph I had to write a 50 line code with about 10 while loops.

What 'good' implementations are there?

Comment: C *or* C++, pick one; there is no C/C++. I'd say Boost.

Comment: Not sure what you're asking for here? Can you elaborate?

Comment: @The GIG: because the structure of the implementation would probably be quite different, since C and C++ have different abstractions and idioms.

Comment: By more specific are you asking us to write this for you?

Comment: So you need something *efficient*? In what respect and for what use case? The adjacency matrix is very efficient if e.g. you are processing [complete graphs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_graph)...

Comment: BTW, the DS that you thought is in fact an adjacency list...

Answer (score 40, accepted):

It really depends on what algorithms you need to implement, there is no silver bullet (and that's shouldn't be a surprise... the general rule about programming is that there's no general rule ;-) ).

I often end up representing directed multigraphs using node/edge structures with pointers... more specifically:

```
struct Node
{
    ... payload ...
    Link *first_in, *last_in, *first_out, *last_out;
};

struct Link
{
    ... payload ...
    Node *from, *to;
    Link *prev_same_from, *next_same_from,
         *prev_same_to, *next_same_to;
};
```

In other words each node has a doubly-linked list of incoming links and a doubly-linked list of outgoing links. Each link knows `from` and `to` nodes and is at the same time in two different doubly-linked lists: the list of all links coming out from the same `from` node and the list of all links arriving at the same `to` node.

The pointers `prev_same_from` and `next_same_from` are used when following the chain of all the links coming out **from** the same node; the pointers `prev_same_to` and `next_same_to` are instead used when managing the chain of all the links pointing **to** the same node.

[image: Data structure diagram]

It's a lot of pointer twiddling (so unless you love pointers just forget about this) but query and update operations are efficient; for example adding a node or a link is O(1), removing a link is O(1) and removing a node x is O(deg(x)).

Of course depending on the problem, payload size, graph size, graph density this approach can be way overkilling or too much demanding for memory (in addition to payload you've 4 pointers per node and 6 pointers per link).

A similar structure full implementation can be found [here](https://github.com/6502/cppgraph).

Comment: Can you explain prev_same_from, next_same_fron, prev_same_to, and next_same_to? I don't understand what they do from your description.

Comment: @BradyDean: I've added some more detail and a picture describing the structure. Filled dots are NULL pointers, dots are pointers with red color for the doubly linked list of all incoming links and blue color for the doubly linked list of all outgoing links.

Comment: Wow thank you. I drew my own picture too and realized each link essentially knows what directions it can travel in

Answer (score 46):

Below is a implementation of Graph Data Structure in C++ as Adjacency List.

I have used STL vector for representation of vertices and STL pair for denoting edge and destination vertex.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

struct vertex {
    typedef pair<int, vertex*> ve;
    vector<ve> adj; //cost of edge, destination vertex
    string name;
    vertex(string s) : name(s) {}
};

class graph
{
public:
    typedef map<string, vertex *> vmap;
    vmap work;
    void addvertex(const string&);
    void addedge(const string& from, const string& to, double cost);
};

void graph::addvertex(const string &name)
{
    vmap::iterator itr = work.find(name);
    if (itr == work.end())
    {
        vertex *v;
        v = new vertex(name);
        work[name] = v;
        return;
    }
    cout << "\nVertex already exists!";
}

void graph::addedge(const string& from, const string& to, double cost)
{
    vertex *f = (work.find(from)->second);
    vertex *t = (work.find(to)->second);
    pair<int, vertex *> edge = make_pair(cost, t);
    f->adj.push_back(edge);
}
```

Comment: Nice! Just a minor question: Why do you name your vertex map "work"?

Comment: Awesome! Do not forget to either change `double cost` in `addedge()` to `int cost`, or change `pair<int, vertex*>` in `struct vertex {};` to `pair <double, vertex*>`

Comment: Why make vertex using `struct` and graph using `class`? Thanks

Comment: Should `v = new vertex(name)` be deleted somewhere?

Comment: Why not use a multimap instead of a vector of pairs?

Answer (score 24):

This question is ancient but for some reason I can't seem to get it out of my mind.

While all of the solutions do provide an implementation of graphs, they are also all very verbose. They are simply not elegant.

Instead of inventing your own graph class all you *really* need is a way to tell that one point is connected to another -- for that, `std::map` and `std::unordered_map` work perfectly fine. Simply, define a graph as a map between nodes and lists of edges. If you don't need extra data on the edge, a list of end nodes will do just fine.

Thus a succinct graph in C++, could be implemented like so:

```
using graph = std::map<int, std::vector<int>>;
```

Or, if you need additional data,

```
struct edge {
    int nodes[2];
    float cost; // add more if you need it
};

using graph = std::map<int, std::vector<edge>>;
```

Now your graph structure will plug nicely into the rest of the language and you don't have to remember any new clunky interface -- the old clunky interface will do just fine.

No benchmarks, but I have a feeling this will also outperform the other suggestions here.

NB: the `int`s are not indices -- they are identifiers.

Comment: elegant, but isn't "vertex" a synonym of "node"?

Comment: @TheHowlingHoaschd It is.

Comment: How about a vector instead of the `map`? Simply use the index as NodeID. It will yield O(1) lookup.

Comment: Because the `int`s are not indices, but indentifiers. If you are certain that the graph contains a contigous set of identifiers, a vector would do fine (and the performance benefits would probably be much better than the O(log(n)) -> O(1) change suggests). Also, note that `int` can be negative, so if you want to use a `vector`, you would have to deal with that -- using any unsigned type would suffice.

Answer (score 9):

The most common representations are probably these two:

- [Adjacency list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_list)
- [Adjacency matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_matrix)

Of these two the [adjacency matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_matrix) is the simplest, as long as you don't mind having a (possibly huge) `n * n` array, where `n` is the number of vertices. Depending on the base type of the array, you can even store edge weights for use in e.g. shortest path discovery algorithms.

Comment: Sorry, I meant something more specific.

Answer (score 3):

I prefer using an adjacency list of **Indices ( not pointers )**

```
typedef std::vector< Vertex > Vertices;
typedef std::set <int> Neighbours;


struct Vertex {
private:
   int data;
public:
   Neighbours neighbours;

   Vertex( int d ): data(d) {}
   Vertex( ): data(-1) {}

   bool operator<( const Vertex& ref ) const {
      return ( ref.data < data );
   }
   bool operator==( const Vertex& ref ) const {
      return ( ref.data == data );
   }
};

class Graph
{
private :
   Vertices vertices;
}

void Graph::addEdgeIndices ( int index1, int index2 ) {
  vertices[ index1 ].neighbours.insert( index2 );
}


Vertices::iterator Graph::findVertexIndex( int val, bool& res )
{
   std::vector<Vertex>::iterator it;
   Vertex v(val);
   it = std::find( vertices.begin(), vertices.end(), v );
   if (it != vertices.end()){
        res = true;
       return it;
   } else {
       res = false;
       return vertices.end();
   }
}

void Graph::addEdge ( int n1, int n2 ) {

   bool foundNet1 = false, foundNet2 = false;
   Vertices::iterator vit1 = findVertexIndex( n1, foundNet1 );
   int node1Index = -1, node2Index = -1;
   if ( !foundNet1 ) {
      Vertex v1( n1 );
      vertices.push_back( v1 );
      node1Index = vertices.size() - 1;
   } else {
      node1Index = vit1 - vertices.begin();
   }
   Vertices::iterator vit2 = findVertexIndex( n2, foundNet2);
   if ( !foundNet2 ) {
      Vertex v2( n2 );
      vertices.push_back( v2 );
      node2Index = vertices.size() - 1;
   } else {
      node2Index = vit2 - vertices.begin();
   }

   assert( ( node1Index > -1 ) && ( node1Index <  vertices.size()));
   assert( ( node2Index > -1 ) && ( node2Index <  vertices.size()));

   addEdgeIndices( node1Index, node2Index );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There can be an even simpler representation assuming that one has to only test graph algorithms not use them(graph) else where. This can be as a map from vertices to their adjacency lists as shown below :-

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

/* implement the graph as a map from the integer index as a key to the   adjacency list
 * of the graph implemented as a vector being the value of each individual key. The
 * program will be given a matrix of numbers, the first element of each row will
 * represent the head of the adjacency list and the rest of the elements will be the
 * list of that element in the graph.
*/

typedef map<int, vector<int> > graphType;

int main(){

graphType graph;
int vertices = 0;

cout << "Please enter the number of vertices in the graph :- " << endl;
cin >> vertices;
if(vertices <= 0){
    cout << "The number of vertices in the graph can't be less than or equal to 0." << endl;
    exit(0);
}

cout << "Please enter the elements of the graph, as an adjacency list, one row after another. " << endl;
for(int i = 0; i <= vertices; i++){

    vector<int> adjList;                    //the vector corresponding to the adjacency list of each vertex

    int key = -1, listValue = -1;
    string listString;
    getline(cin, listString);
    if(i != 0){
        istringstream iss(listString);
        iss >> key;
        iss >> listValue;
        if(listValue != -1){
            adjList.push_back(listValue);
            for(; iss >> listValue; ){
                adjList.push_back(listValue);
            }
            graph.insert(graphType::value_type(key, adjList));
        }
        else
            graph.insert(graphType::value_type(key, adjList));
    }
}

//print the elements of the graph
cout << "The graph that you entered :- " << endl;
for(graphType::const_iterator iterator = graph.begin(); iterator != graph.end(); ++iterator){
    cout << "Key : " << iterator->first << ", values : ";

    vector<int>::const_iterator vectBegIter = iterator->second.begin();
    vector<int>::const_iterator vectEndIter = iterator->second.end();
    for(; vectBegIter != vectEndIter; ++vectBegIter){
        cout << *(vectBegIter) << ", ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a basic implementation of a graph. 
Note: I use vertex which is chained to next vertex. And each vertex has a list pointing to adjacent nodes.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


// 1 ->2 
// 1->4
// 2 ->3
// 4->3
// 4 -> 5
// Adjacency list
// 1->2->3-null
// 2->3->null
//4->5->null;

// Structure of a vertex
struct vertex {
   int i;
   struct node *list;
   struct vertex *next;
};
typedef struct vertex * VPTR;

// Struct of adjacency list
struct node {
    struct vertex * n;
    struct node *next;
};

typedef struct node * NODEPTR;

class Graph {
    public:
        // list of nodes chained together
        VPTR V;
        Graph() {
            V = NULL;
        }
        void addEdge(int, int);
        VPTR  addVertex(int);
        VPTR existVertex(int i);
        void listVertex();
};

// If vertex exist, it returns its pointer else returns NULL
VPTR Graph::existVertex(int i) {
    VPTR temp  = V;
    while(temp != NULL) {
        if(temp->i == i) {
            return temp;
        }
        temp = temp->next;
    }
   return NULL;
}
// Add a new vertex to the end of the vertex list
VPTR Graph::addVertex(int i) {
    VPTR temp = new(struct vertex);
    temp->list = NULL;
    temp->i = i;
    temp->next = NULL;

    VPTR *curr = &V;
    while(*curr) {
        curr = &(*curr)->next;
    }
    *curr = temp;
    return temp;
}

// Add a node from vertex i to j. 
// first check if i and j exists. If not first add the vertex
// and then add entry of j into adjacency list of i
void Graph::addEdge(int i, int j) {

    VPTR v_i = existVertex(i);   
    VPTR v_j = existVertex(j);   
    if(v_i == NULL) {
        v_i = addVertex(i);
    }
    if(v_j == NULL) {
        v_j = addVertex(j);
    }

    NODEPTR *temp = &(v_i->list);
    while(*temp) {
        temp = &(*temp)->next;
    }
    *temp = new(struct node);
    (*temp)->n = v_j;
    (*temp)->next = NULL;
}
// List all the vertex.
void Graph::listVertex() {
    VPTR temp = V;
    while(temp) {
        cout <<temp->i <<" ";
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    cout <<"\n";

}

// Client program
int main() {
    Graph G;
    G.addEdge(1, 2);
    G.listVertex();

}
```

With the above code, you can expand to do DFS/BFS etc.