# C++ graph implemation

Tags: c++, data-structures, graph

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Graph implementation C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5493474/graph-implementation-c)

Hi

I was wondering about a quick to write implementation of a graph in c++. I need the data structure to be easy to manipulate and use graph algorithms(such as BFS,DFS, Kruskal, Dijkstra...).
I need this implementation for an algorithms Olympiad, so the easier to write the data structure the better.

Can you suggest such DS(main structs or classes and what will be in them). I know that an Adjacency list and Adjacency matrix are the main possibilities, but I mean a more detailed **code** sample.

For example I thought about this DS last time I had to implement a graph for DFS:

```
struct Edge {
  int start;
  int end;
  struct Edge* nextEdge;
}
```

and then used a array of size n containing in its i'th place the Edge List(struct Edge) representing the edges starting in the i'th node.

but when trying to DFS on this graph I had to write a 50 line code with about 10 while loops.

What 'good' implementations are there?

Comment: exactly the same as the already answered question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5493474/graph-implemation-c

Comment: Why are you posting the same question again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of maintaining  nextEdge list inside an edge, you should implement them separately.

```
struct Edge
{
int start;
int end;
};
```

Since you are using C++ and it's for a Olympiad, better use everything STL has to offer.

Therefore, store the Edges inside a **vector**. This would be helpful for algorithms that iterate over Edges instead of nodes.

If you need to traverse from Node to Node (BFS,DFS), it's better to maintain an adjacency list.

Again use an array of vector for this purpose.

```
vector<int> adj[MAXNODE];
```