# Implementation of Adjacent Matrix with 2D vectors c++

Tags: c++, graph, vector

I am a beginner in c++ and I have worked on vectors just not on 2D vectors. I have surfed a lot, but data on internet is very specific related to 2D vectors.
I need to build a graph given an input file and then apply Kruskal's algorithm for minimum spanning tree.

My approach:

```
A1, A2, A3.....An would be the first row and col of my 2d Vectors and they will
 contain name. I will read the input file and start matching the names.
 And then at graph[i][j] I will put the weight.

     A1 A2 A3......  

A1   w  w  w ....... 
A2   w  w  w .......
A3   w  w  w .......
```

.
.
.
.
Now I am trying something like this:

```
struct mat{
       string name;
}

int main(){
vector<vector<mat>> matrix;
// In order to insert
vector<mat> tempVec;
tempVec[0].name = "stack";
matrix.push_back(tempVec);
}
```

Now I have no idea that when I do `tempVec[0].name`, 0 indicates which row or col of Matrix. If it indicates row then how do I know which col is being accessed. 
I mean `vector.push_back(tempVec)`, assigns which position in my Matrix to data. I know I can access individual elements like Matrix[i][j]. But How can I assign weight to a particular row, col position and then access it.

Further do you think will be a good implementation for Kruskal's Method.

Please be simple in your code and explanatory. 
And thanks in advance.

Comment: sure it is not matrix.push_back(tempVec); ?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5493474/graph-implementation-c

Comment: @user2151446 I want to do this using 2d Vectors. I think it will be much easier.

Comment: @FlorisVelleman I don't understand your question ????

Answer (score 0):

Using `vector<vector<T>>` is a fairly suboptimal way to represent matrices, even though it is often used. It would be better to make a one-dimensional `vector<T>` of size rows x cols. You can then index it as follows (assuming you follow C-style row major ordering):

```
vector<mat> matrix(rows*cols);
...
element_ij=matrix[i*cols+j];
```

In your current code, you never insert anything into matrix:

```
vector<vector<mat>> matrix;
// In order to insert
vector<mat> tempVec;
tempVec[0].name = "stack";
vector.push_back(tempVec);
```

I assume the last line should be `matrix.push_back(tempVec);`.

Comment: I made the change it was supposed to be matrix.push_back.....So do you think now it would represent 2D Matrix.

Comment: It certainly is *a* way to represent a 2D matrix.

Comment: So how do I know which row and col is accessed. That is my real Question.

Comment: When you would use this kind of setup, it is up to you to define the indexing scheme and stick to it. Typically `matrix[i][j]` refers to row i, column j. If you would simply do `matrix[i]`, you will get a `vector<mat>` as a result. It's up to you to choose whether your outermost index refers to columns or rows.