# Worst case memory for Graph data structure

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, graph

I could see in many books that the worst case memory requirement for graphs is O(V). But, If I have not mistaken, graphs are usually represented as adjacency matrix and not by the creation of nodes ( as in linked list / trees ). So, for a graph containing 5 vertices, I need 5x5 matrix which is O(V^2). They why do they say it as O(V)?

Am I missing something somewhere? Sorry if the question is too naive.

Comment: Can you please provide an exact quote from *one* of the books that makes such a statement?

Comment: @Jason: See the famous CLRS, they too mention as O(V).

Comment: It can be represented using linked list.

Comment: @shar: Again, please provide an exact quote.

Comment: See this SO question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3287003/three-ways-to-store-a-graph-in-memory-advantages-and-disadvantages

Comment: @Jayram: That clears my doubt. Thanks, so it depends on the way you represent!! It could be O(V) or O(V^2) also.

Comment: Yes graphs can be represented by an adjacency matrix which would require O(n^2) space where n is the number of nodes or vertices. You can also represent the graph as an adjacency list which would take O(max{ m, n}) where m is the number of edges. I recommend this [video](https://class.coursera.org/algo-2012-002/lecture/32) to see why.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The three main ways of representing a graph are:

- Adjacency matrix - Θ(|V|²) space.
- Adjacency list - Θ(|V| + |E|) space.
- Collection of node objects/structs with pointers to one another - This is basically just another way of representing an adjacency list. Θ(|V| + |E|). (Remember that pointers require memory too.)

Since we're talking worst case, all of these reduce to Θ(|V|²) since that's the maximum number of edges in a graph.

I'm guessing you misread the book. They probably weren't talking about the space required to store the graph structure itself, but rather the amount of *extra* space required for some graph algorithm.

Comment: This is what CLRS mentioned in the book, at least in the 3rd edition .

Answer (score 2):

If what you say is true, it's possible they are referring to *other* ways to represent a graph, other than using an adjacency matrix and are possibly making an edge-density assumption. One way is, for each vertex, just store a list of pointers / references to its neighbors (called an adjacency list). This would be `O(|V| + |E|)`. *If* we assume `|E| ~ |V|`, which is an assumption we do sometimes see, then we have `O(|V|)` space. But note that in the worst-case, `|E| ~ |V|^2` and so even this approach to representing a graph is `O(|V|^2)` in the *worst case*.

Look, it's quite simple; there's no escaping the fact that in the worst case `|E| ~ |V|^2`. There can not possibly be, in general, a representation of `E` that in the worst case is *not* `O(|V|^2)`.

But, it'd be nice to have an exact quote to work with. This is *important*. We don't want to find ourselves tearing apart your misunderstanding of a correct statement.

Comment: Since the OP is asking about *worst case* memory usage, I'm thinking `|E| ~ |V|` isn't a safe assumption in this case.

Comment: I did not make such an assumption. I said one way the OP's understanding of the book can be true is *if* the book made such an assumption. I'm being generous to the OP, because it's clear that in general without some sort of assumption, the OP misunderstood. It's clear there are only two possibilities: either the OP misunderstood the book, or the book did in fact have some sort of assumption that makes the statement true.