# Merits of implementing tree by array over pointer?

Tags: c++, tree

Recently I learnt implementing tree by struct such as

```
struct Node{
     Node *parent;
     vector<Node*> child;
     Node(void):parent(nullptr){}
}
```

I thought this is a pretty straight forward way to implement tree,
and it is also easier to include more stuff for process within the struct.

However, I noticed in many people's code,
they prefer using an array instead of pointer.
I could understand this for Binary Tree as it is pretty easy to do it by array too
, but why on other more complex graph?

Comment: You probably don't want to use [pointers at all](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory).

Comment: The way I learned it in class is, if you are trying to represent a connected Graph using this kind of structure, then an Array of arrays is better for Dense graphs (because the array will be pretty much full), but if the Graph is sparse (less connections) use pointers (array of lists) instead. The choice of the data structure always depends on the application !

Comment: @ πάντα ῥεῖ  Why not at all? I don't see the reasoning behind it, wouldn't an array waste a lot more memory if the tree is not perfectly filled?

Comment: Consider this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3287003/three-ways-to-store-a-graph-in-memory-advantages-and-disadvantages. You're currently using a node with pointers to edges. That posts talks about various other ways of storing connected graphs and their advantages and limitations. Keep in mind that a general tree structure is just a connected acyclic graph.

Comment: Merits of implementing tree by array over pointer? or Merits of implementing tree by array over structure? In your title you are referring to "Merits of implementing tree by array over pointer" but in your write-up I find that you feel accessing arrays are easier than structures. Is it that you want to use arrays instead of structures? or Is it that you want to use arrays instead of pointers? Please clarify on this one...so that I might be able to give you a solution.

Comment: I personally prefer using structure to implement the tree, but I find out many are using array instead, so I would like to learn the arguments of their side to see whether I am missing out something huge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Skiena:2008:ADM:1410219 and Cormen:2001:IA:580470 comparing adjacency matrices and adjacency lists for *graphs* yields that:

- Adjacency matrices are faster for testing if `(x, y)`, two nodes, have a connecting edge
- Adjacency lists are faster for finding the degree (the amount of neighbours) of a given node.
- A graph with `m` nodes and `n` edges consumes `m + n` space if implemented using adjacency lists compared to `n^2` for adjacency matrices.
- Adjacency matrices uses *slightly* less memory for big graphs.
- Edge insertion/deletion performs in `O(1)` when using adjacency matrices.
- Traversing a graph implemented using adjacency lists performs in `Θ(m + n)` and matrices `Θ(n^2)`

If a graph has many vertices but few edges adjacency matrices consume excessive memory.

So in general adjacency lists perform better.

Comment: For space taken by an adjacency matrix, is it actually m^2 (the number of nodes squared)?