# efficient way to store graph with 26 millions edges

Tags: java, graph, bigdata

I'm relatively new to graph processing and 
I have a graph with 26 million edges along with nodes and I want to run k-shortest path algorithm on it, currently, I'm using a hashmap to store the edges, but I get java heap space out of memory error (which is understandable).

So my question is what is the most efficient way to store this graph so that I don't get memory spill error and I can efficiently run k-shortest path algorithm.
Is there some in-memory database specifically for graphs?

Comment: This post might be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3287003/three-ways-to-store-a-graph-in-memory-advantages-and-disadvantages

Answer (score 0):

There are different in memory graph databases (native and non-native in terms of processing and storage). You can find the three most popular of them in the following:

- Bitsy is a small, fast, embeddable, durable in-memory graph database that implements the Blueprints API.
- [Graph Engine](https://www.graphengine.io/) (GE) is a distributed in-memory data processing engine, underpinned by a strongly-typed RAM store and a general distributed computation engine.
- [Grapholytic](https://grapholytic.miosoft.eu/) is the only database with automatic based distribution of graphs to cluster nodes using advanced machine learning algorithms. No Limits for scalability. Binding Data to CPU power: enabling parallel processing and advanced performance for analytical processing. Combining In-Memory Computation and Low Cost storage for enterprise computation scenarios.

Also, you can use some popular cache systems such as Redis. If you want to store the adjacency matrix inline memory, Redis could be a plausible choice.